# Regression of citations by article title

Tags: nlp, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset of some lines (article titles) and the number of citations for an article with this title, what is the best way to build a regression model? I have an idea to launch TF-IDF and use a linear model, but I don't yet understand how true this is. There are about 5000 titles, all of them from the same topic.

Maybe there is some common name for such a task?

Comment: To predict what?

Comment: Number of citations by article title

Comment: The name of the task is just sequence regression; when searching for it you'll come across a lot of examples of sequence prediction, but it's not the same.

Comment: You could make a bag of words from the titles and do e.g. Lasso regression on the BOW features.